# How to get Ansible facts within inventory plugin

Tags: python, ansible

I'm not sure if this is possible as I'm trying to understand Ansible's module development and cannot seem to find an example beyond the "Hello World".

What I'm trying to do:

Our servers are provisioned internally by our IT department. I would like to dynamically create an inventory and use Ansible facts to determine server type. I have this initially working as separate Python scripts within a playbook. The process is as follows:

1. Run nmap to find hosts and output to `/path/to/nmap_hosts.`
2. Execute `ansible gather_facts -i /path/to/nmap_hosts | tee /path/to/facts_file`
3. Read `/path/to/facts_file`, extract data gathered from `/etc/ansible/facts.d/myfacts.fact` on host.
4. Generate dynamic inventory file containing hosts/groups based on metadata from `/etc/ansible/facts.d/myfacts.fact`.
5. Refresh inventory using `meta: refresh_inventory`.

Instead of having separate tasks within a playbook, I'm trying to achieve the same within a custom inventory plugin. I've been digging into Ansible source trying to understand if it is even possible to do `ansible gather_facts` within `BaseInventoryPlugin.parse()`.

I've dove deep into the following source code and cannot determine how to do this. Is this even possible? 
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/executor/module_common.py
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/basic.py
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/module_utils/facts/compat.py

Comment: Are you aware of Ansible's nmap inventory plugin? Could it not address your need?

Comment: To add to what Mxx said, it sounds like you are also trying to re-implement the `gather_facts: yes` or `- setup:` tasks by hand, which sounds suspicious

Comment: It definitely is suspicious which is why I wonder if what I'm doing is even possible within a plugin. As I stated in my post, I can do this with multiple steps in a playbook. In regards to the existing ```nmap``` plugin, it doesn't find any of my hosts even if I explicitly set it to an IP. That is why I implemented my own, which was easy. I'm just not sure how to get the facts within the plugin. Documentation is lacking, and I haven't found a good example.

Comment: +1 to the notion that Ansible's community.nmap documentation is atrocious. nmap can create an inventory based off MAC addresses, so it's an ideal example for dynamic inventory (arguably MAC scanning should be built-in to Ansible)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After conferring with the developer forums, I was able to determine that this isn't possible. It makes sense as fact gathering can be disabled.